# find -exec bash -c {} +: why only one file of found two?

Tags: bash, shell, find

```
touch 1.txt 2.txt
find . -name "[12].txt" -exec sh -c 'echo "${1}"' sh {} + -exec echo {} +
./2.txt
./2.txt ./1.txt
```

Why `echo` within `sh -c` outputs only one file? Today I thought I understood how `find` works from [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705/understanding-the-exec-option-of-find) but now puzzled again. Got same result for `-exec bash`. TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With:

```
-exec sh -c 'echo "${1}"' sh {} +
```

`find` passes as many as possible of the files that it found to `sh`, and you're asking `sh` to pass the first one (`${1}` or `$1` for short) to `echo`. To pass all of them, use `"$@"` instead:

```
-exec sh -c 'echo "$@"' sh {} +
```

Or for `sh` to call `echo` once for each of them, use a loop over the positional parameter (positional parameters are what `for` loops loop over by default):

```
-exec sh -c 'for file do
               echo "$file"
             done' sh {} +
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems I've read not too attentively. Now I face another issue with find {} +: `find . -name "[12].txt" -exec cmp {} + -exec sh -c 'if [ "${1}" < "${2}" ] ; then echo "${1}" ; fi' sh {} +` even as `cmp` outputs "files differ" next `exec` with `echo` runs. Why? How testing with exec works? P.S. I know it might be another Q. If not answered as comment, I plan to post it.

Comment: @AlexMartian https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Multiple-Files : "Action: -exec command {} + .... The result is always true."

Comment: Thanks. My bad, trying to grasp new code when tired. In the example `{} +` was used only at the end, check was done with `{} ;`.